# How to target value in Accordion?

Tags: typescript

How can I target value in accordion? I would like to find specific value, and proceed in logic. Thank you

```
const obj = [
        {select: 'select'},
        {even: 'even/odd nums'},
        {small: 'smallest/highest'}
       ]

// handleChange function return this
// <select name="selectMethod" id="selectMethod" class="mx-5">...</select>

 const handleChange = (e:MouseEvent): void => {
    if (e.target instanceof Element) { console.log(e.currentTarget)}
  }  


<select name="selectMethod" id="selectMethod" className='mx-5' 
        onChange={handleChange}>      // I dont know how to  select value of option
        {obj.map((x, i) => (
          <option key={i} value={Object.keys(x)}  >
            {Object.values(x)}
          </option>
        ))} 
 </select>
```

I am trying to learn typescript but its bit hard to find useful tutorial, everybody show just basic syntax.